# Meteor white screen instead of splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, splash-screen

I've created a new app with Meteor (1.2.1). If I start it once I get a splash screen. Then I stop my app with

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

and if I start it again, there is a white screen instead of the splash screen.

The Problem should be reproducible for anyone. Create a new blank meteor app and run it on your android device. If you start it the first time you will see the meteor splash screen and if you close the app (with the back button on your device) and start it a second time you will get a white screen instead.

In older versions of meteor (1.1.0.2) I had no such problem.

Have anyone a solution how I can get the splash screen every single time.

(I've tested it with Samsung S4 Mini and HTC Evo 3d)

Comment: I dont know about meteor, but in Native the Zygote is the first thing to load. You can specifically design your Splash screen using themes to prevent the Zygote from coming into notice. [Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) is an insight.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround for my problem.

I've added an older release of cordova-plugin-splashscreen to my project. From https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/releases

```
# version 2.0 (current version is 2.1)    
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-splashscreen@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tarball/d23ea4e01162a78f692bb246776f2a5b3a1da14b
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but your fix did not work for me. Any insights into how this might be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue, after look at the PhoneGap document, I found it's a default behaviour for phonegap splash screen plugin. You can see it [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/index.html#android-quirks)

> "SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" preference is also optional and defaults to true. When set to true splash screen will only appear on application launch. However, if you plan to use navigator.app.exitApp() to close application and force splash screen appear on next launch, you should set this property to false (this also applies to closing the App with Back button).

So all you need to do is add this into your mobile-config file

```
App.setPreference('SplashShowOnlyFirstTime', 'false');
```